# Presenting TableView list on iPad in view/subview without taking up the whole screen, no splitview

Tags: xcode5, ipad

I am STUCK stuck on a conceptual/practical layout problem for the iPad.  In short, we need to show a list of entries in a TableView in landscape on the iPad, but we can't use SplitView for several reasons, and we can't push the tableview on the stack since there's so much unused space... So we can't figure out a solid way to present the table.

We have a ViewController that gives people some options for searching for data in a NavigationController stack. We need a UITableView to show people a list of entries, then when they click on each entry, it goes to another ViewController that shows more data about that entry. That's fine, but we can't just push the TableView on it's own because 2/3rds of the screen (it's landscape) is unused. We tried to implement a SplitView [but Apple has restrictions on using one in a stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4213097/best-way-to-switch-between-uisplitviewcontroller-and-other-view-controllers), and we can't figure a way around it, despite it being a mostly ideal solution in our case. The other problem is that it appears we can't use a SplitView in a NavigationController stack.

I had made the search results TableView a subview of our main ViewController view controller, and have it slide in to show the list of entries, but then it's not part of the NavigationController and there was some debate about whether that's bad practice, not to mention there's no way to go "back" on the navigation controller to dismiss the subview... Additionally, when they go to the entry view and go back in the navigation, the TableView is gone.

Please forgive the kind of pseudo-conceptual nature of our problem, here. I've literally been grappling with this for a week and have been avoiding asking SO, since I originally didn't feel like it was the right kind of question, but I'm seeing a lot of people with similar problems that seem to not have a solution -- [or at least a non-hacky one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9715396/official-alternative-to-implement-splitview-as-a-subview-for-an-ipad-app) and I am totally out of ideas and at my wit's end.